# Certificates issue

Tags: windows, certificate

**The background**

We have been using certificates to access a third party service from a windows 2003 box. The certificate recently expired so we went about getting a new one from the third party(Experian). We were provided with two certs to be installed in the "Trusted Root Certication Authorities" and two to be installed in the "Intermediate Certification Authorities" and then the main one that gets installed to the Personal\Certificates.

I know the certs are working when I can access a URL. If I install the certs allowing the cert decide where to install themselves (local Computer or Current User) they install to the current user store. I can then access the URL ... all is well.

**The Issue**

However I need the certificates to work on a computer level rather than a user level. So I move the certs to the relative Local Computer store locations however this does not work. I now cannot access the URL as any user. I tried deleting them all out and importing them directly into the required local computer cert location... still no joy. I tried installing them as the local admin .... still no joy. Tried granting access to the certs via winhttpcertcfg to everyone/specific users etc, still no joy.

Is it possible that the cert is designed to work for only one user? Is there something I am missing to make this work? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As admin you should:

1. run mmc
2. add snapin for certificates (for local computer)
3. add root CAs to "Trusted Root Certication Authorities"
4. add intermediate CAs to "Intermediate Certification Authorities"
5. add end entity certificate with private key (it should be a .p12 or .pfx file) to Personal\Certificates
6. grant rights to user that can access the private key using winhttpcertcfg utility

and it should work (at least it did for me every time).

If you don't have private key corresponding to end entity certificate (because you deleted them all) then you need to get a new one from third party(Experian).